# How to use Javascript to set value of page element from APEX_ITEM

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm writing some code in Oracle Apex and I don't come from a development background, so pardon my bad code.  I'm dynamically generating a form and I want to set a hidden page item when the user changes the value of a specific form element.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
    select APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(2,base_data_seq_nbr)||APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(6,case when substr(description,0,1)= chr(49838) then substr(description,-(length(description)-1)) else description end)||APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(7,case when substr(description,0,1)= chr(49838) then 1 else 0 end)||APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(9,
                 data_select(replace(replace(trim(substr(field_name,-(length(field_name)-instr(field_name,',',1)))),'BSBR',''),'C','L'), substr(field_name,0,instr(field_name,',',1)-1), :P721_XCASE,:P721_XRETSTAT,:P721_XID,:P721_XCUSNUM,:P721_DB_ID))||case when substr(description,0,1)= chr(49838)
         then '<img src="/i/themes/theme_2/images/required.gif" alt="Value Required" alt="Value Required" />'
         else null
       end as req_ind,
   case when substr(description,0,1)= chr(49838)
         then substr(description,-(length(description)-1))
         else description
       end as description,
   APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP(1,rownum,
                 to_date(data_select(replace(replace(trim(substr(field_name,-(length(field_name)-instr(field_name,',',1)))),'BSBR',''),'C','L'), substr(field_name,0,instr(field_name,',',1)-1), :P721_XCASE,:P721_XRETSTAT,:P721_XID,:P721_XCUSNUM,:P721_DB_ID),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY',10,10,'onkeyup="javascript:FormatDate(this);"' ||case when instr(substr(field_name,1,4),'DOB,',1)>0 then ' onchange="javascript:$s(''P721_DOB_RBD'',this);"' end,'datepicker_'||rownum)
        end
   end as field_format
from bcvsown.bcvs_base_data
    inner join v_lookup v
    on v.value_seq = stmt_type 
left join (select * from apex_collections where collection_name = 'ERR_COLLECTION') ac
    on base_data_seq_nbr=ac.n001
where caseno = :P721_XCASE
and v.value_cd = case when :P721_XDE_SEQ > 1 then decode(:P721_XIS_BSRS,'true','BSRS','BET') else v.value_cd end
and db_id = :P721_DB_ID
and v.type_cd = 'STMT_TYPE' 
order by base_data_seq_nbr
```

The page renders as expected with no error and the page source shows the javascript settings   `(onchange="javascript:$s(''P721_DOB_RBD'',this);")` applied only to the elements I am aiming for.  But when I change the element, it doesn't seem to set the value of the hidden page item `(P721_DOB_RBD)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No offense, that markup is quite horrible. Take the time to properly format and indent your code!

As for your problem, [this is the Oracle apex javascript apis reference for $s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aexjs/global.html#$s)

> ```
> $s(pNd, pValue, pDisplayValue, pSuppressChangeEvent)
> ```
>
> Given a DOM node or string ID (pNd), this function sets the
> Application Express item value taking into account the item type. The
> pDisplayValue is optional. If used for a page item of type "Popup LOV"
> where the attribute "Input Field" = "Not Enterable, Show Display Value
> and Store Return Value", it is used to set the "Input Field". The
> value of pValue is stored in the hidden return field. The
> pSuppressChangeEvent parameter is optional. Passing either FALSE or
> not passing this parameter value results in a change event firing for
> the item being set. Pass TRUE to prevent the change event from firing
> for the item being set.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> pNd (DOM Node | string ID)
> pValue  (String | Array)
> pDisplayValue(String)
> pSuppressChangeEvent(Boolean)
> ```

Passing on `this` won't work. That will pass on the object, when you want to pass on a value. Since you're creating a `APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP` which will generate an `input` item, you will need the `value` of the item at the time the `change` event happens. You can do that by using `$v` ([ref](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.2/aexjs/global.html#$v))

> ```
> $v(pNd)
> ```
>
> Given a DOM node or string ID (pNd), this function returns the value
> of an Application Express item in the same format as it would be
> posted.
>
> Parameters
>
> ```
> pNd (DOM Node | string ID)
> ```

So, try with this:

```
(onchange="javascript:$s(''P721_DOB_RBD'',$v(this));")
```

Answer (score 0):

Years later - To format the code, use sqldeveloper copy the code to a sqldeveloper sql worksheet,
 right click and select format.

```
 SELECT APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(2,base_data_seq_nbr)
  ||APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(6,
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(description,0,1)= chr(49838)
    THEN SUBSTR(description,-(LENGTH(description)-1))
    ELSE description
  END)
  ||APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(7,
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(description,0,1)= chr(49838)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END)
  ||APEX_ITEM.HIDDEN(9, data_select(REPLACE(REPLACE(trim(SUBSTR(field_name,-(LENGTH(field_name)-instr(field_name,',',1)))),'BSBR',''),'C','L'), SUBSTR(field_name,0,instr(field_name,',',1)-1), :P721_XCASE,:P721_XRETSTAT,:P721_XID,:P721_XCUSNUM,:P721_DB_ID))
  ||
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(description,0,1)= chr(49838)
    THEN '<img src="/i/themes/theme_2/images/required.gif" alt="Value Required" alt="Value Required" />'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS req_ind,
  CASE
    WHEN SUBSTR(description,0,1)= chr(49838)
    THEN SUBSTR(description,-(LENGTH(description)-1))
    ELSE description
  END AS description,
  APEX_ITEM.DATE_POPUP(1,rownum, to_date(data_select(REPLACE(REPLACE(trim(SUBSTR(field_name,-(LENGTH(field_name)-instr(field_name,',',1)))),'BSBR',''),'C','L'), SUBSTR(field_name,0,instr(field_name,',',1)-1), :P721_XCASE,:P721_XRETSTAT,:P721_XID,:P721_XCUSNUM,:P721_DB_ID),'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY',10,10,'onkeyup="javascript:FormatDate(this);"'
  ||
  CASE
    WHEN instr(SUBSTR(field_name,1,4),'DOB,',1)>0
    THEN ' onchange="javascript:$s(''P721_DOB_RBD'',this);"'
  END,'datepicker_'
  ||rownum)
END
END AS field_format
FROM bcvsown.bcvs_base_data
INNER JOIN v_lookup v
ON v.value_seq = stmt_type
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM apex_collections WHERE collection_name = 'ERR_COLLECTION'
  ) ac
ON base_data_seq_nbr=ac.n001
WHERE caseno        = :P721_XCASE
AND v.value_cd      =
  CASE
    WHEN :P721_XDE_SEQ > 1
    THEN DECODE(:P721_XIS_BSRS,'true','BSRS','BET')
    ELSE v.value_cd
  END
AND db_id     = :P721_DB_ID
AND v.type_cd = 'STMT_TYPE'
ORDER BY base_data_seq_nbr
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value application items in Javascript, there is no way to  except one. You can set page level items in Javascript use:

```
 $s(':P12_Item','value');
```

You can get the page level item value using:

```
$v('page item')
```

You can get Application item value in JS using

```
 &APP_ITEM.
```

But you can't set the value application item in Javascript. You have to create a process which will set application item value and call this process from Javascript apex Ajax.

```
<script>
var get = new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,'APPLICATION_PROCESS=SET_APS_CASEIDS',0);

get.addParam('x01',$caseIds);

gReturn = get.get();
if (gReturn) {
window.location='f?p=&APP_ID.:66:&SESSION.::NO:66';
}
</script>
```

In my case I am setting value in application item using Ajax and process and redirect to other page. That page will use the application item value.

Application process code.

First create Application Item from shared component.

```
Name: APS_CASEIDS
Session State protection:unrestricted
```

Create Application Process from shared component.

```
Name:SET_APS_CASEIDS (Name should be match in ajax call).
Process point:On Demand:run this application process when requested by process.
Process Text:


BEGIN

owa_util.mime_header('text/html', FALSE );
htp.p('Cache-Control: no-cache');
htp.p('Pragma: no-cache');
owa_util.http_header_close;

    APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('APS_CASEIDS',APEX_APPLICATION.G_X01);
END;
```